# Expected response code 220 but got code "", with message "" When attempting to send an email using SwiftMailer & localhost

Tags: php, smtp, swiftmailer

I'm relatively new to php so I may be making a stupid mistake but I've spent all afternoon looking through other questions on SO and other sites but none of the solutions have worked for me.

I'm trying to send a simple test email, which I'll later connect to a form, but at the moment the following error occurs.

> Fatal error: Uncaught Swift_TransportException: Expected response code 220 but got code "", with message "" in C:\Users\Simon Alexander\php\vendor\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\AbstractSmtpTransport.php:419 Stack trace: #0 C:\Users\Simon Alexander\php\vendor\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\AbstractSmtpTransport.php(325): Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport->assertResponseCode('', Array) #1 C:\Users\Simon Alexander\php\vendor\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\AbstractSmtpTransport.php(130): Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport->readGreeting() #2 C:\Users\Simon Alexander\php\vendor\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\Mailer.php(67): Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport->start() #3 C:\Users\Simon Alexander\php\site.php(15): Swift_Mailer->send(Object(Swift_Message)) #4 {main} thrown in C:\Users\Simon Alexander\php\vendor\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\AbstractSmtpTransport.php on line 419

At the moment I am using localhost, have enables 2 step verification on google and have gotten the 16 digit app key.

```
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

$transport = (new Swift_SmtpTransport('smtp.gmail.com', 587, 'ssl'))
    ->setUsername('email1@gmail.com')
    ->setPassword('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');

$mailer = new Swift_Mailer($transport);

$message = (new Swift_Message('Wonderful Subject'))
    ->setFrom(array('email1@gmail.com' => 'email1Name'))
    ->setTo(array('email2@gmail.com'))
    ->setBody('This is a test mail.');    

$result = $mailer->send($message);
```

My code is almost identical to the example in the SwiftMailer documentation so I'm rather confused as to what is happening?

Comment: I know this doesn't solve your problem but if you use another mail server configuration does it send mail? The issue, I believe is coming from swiftmailer trying to authenticate to send that email and then never getting a proper response from google. Also make sure you have enabled access for less secure apps in your google account. https://support.google.com/cloudidentity/answer/6260879?hl=en

Comment: I've tried using alternate configurations for Gmail, but none of them worked. Also I have less secure apps enabled but since 2 step authentication is on the option of greyed out telling me to use the custom key.